# Encoding issue with csvhelper and html markup

Tags: csvhelper

I am using csvhelper 15.  My code looks like:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(_csvPath, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                csv.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
                csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                profiles = csv.GetRecords<Profile>().ToList();
            }
        }
```

In one of my fields in the csv i have html markup looks like:

```
<p>Standard Chartered plc on its fully underwritten 2 for 7 rights issue to raise approximately £3.3 billion</p>
```

The pound sign ends up at ? so looks like encoding, I am using utf8 however still an issue on the read.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

CsvHelper uses a `TextReader` and knows nothing about the encoding of the file. That is something that needs to be handled before passing the `TextReader` into `CsvHelper.

The `CultureInfo` that is required in the constructor is used for type conversions. When a `string` is converted into an `int` or `DateTimeOffset`, it uses the `CultureInfo` that is supplied.

In your case, the `?` values are due to the encoding set on the `TextReader` that was supplied to `CsvHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok updated my code to:

```
var westernEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(_csvPath, westernEncoding))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CultureInfo("en-GB")))
            {
                csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                csv.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
                csv.Configuration.Encoding = westernEncoding;

                profiles = csv.GetRecords<Profile>().ToList();
            }
        }
```

Now it works